# An inequality relating to the entries of eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix, where $a_{ii}$ is a real number, and $a_{ji}=\overline{a_{ij}}$ is the complex conjugate of $a_{ij}$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq 3$, i.e $A^t=[\overline{a_{ij}}]$. Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ be eigenvalues of $A$ (not necessarily distinct) and $u_i=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda_i$, $i=1,2,3$. Is this true that
$\sum_{i=1}^3\frac{|x_i\overline{y_i}|}{||u_i||^2}\leq 1$, where $x_i,y_i\in\{a_i,b_i,c_i\}$ (not necessarily distinct)? Is this true in general for an $n\times n$ matrix by replacing $n$ with $3$?

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars (as in $\|u_i\|$) using `\|`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true. The $u_i$ could be the three canonical unit vectors, and then you could choose $x_i=y_i=1$, and then the sum would be $3\gt1$.